# Combining Formulas in One Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to multiply by 2, substract, and roundup.  Here's what I'm trying to do.

Number in the cell A1 is 18,291.

I need one formula that will multiply A1 * 2, and reduce the result by by 33% and then roundup to the nearest 1000.  In this example, the end result should be 25,000.

Thank you.

Comment: I was playing around and came up with this formula, but it doesn't seem to roundup.  Here's the formula l attempted:   =(cell * 2) - ROUNDUP(cell*2, -3) * 33%.  It gave me the result of 22,060.  I expected the result of $23,000.  Help.

Comment: If the value of cell A1 is 18,291, `=ROUND(36579 - (A1 * 2 - 3) * 0.33, -3)`

Comment: Within your comment, you are rounding before multiplying the value by 33%. Therefore, your final value is not rounded. Can you edit your question to highlight the issue you are having? Introducing a second example in a comment is confusing.

Comment: David, thank you for responding.  Correction to my issue.  I final result should be the roundup number.  The 36,579 needs to be calculated, so on my spreadsheet I have A1*2.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

`=ROUNDUP(A1 * 2 * (100% - 33%), -3)` multiplies the value of cell A1 by 2, subtracts 33% of that value, and then rounds up to the nearest thousand.